# In Clojure how to define a global variable which can be accessed from other name space

Tags: clojure

In clojure, What is the best possible way to declare a global variable, the value of which needs to be changed in a function and this global variable need to be accessed in other namespaces

Ex:

```
(ns ..main
 .....) 

(def global_variable nil)
..
(defn main ...

Change the value of global variable here 

) 

Another name space 

 (ns accessvariable ...) 

 (println (main/global_variable))
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This is generally considered a Bad Idea in the Clojure community. Why exactly do you need to do this? What problem are you facing that this would solve?

Comment: Atoms are built for this. That said, there are almost always better ways to approach this sort of problem. If you give us more details, we can help you use Clojure's strengths for your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Elogent and WolfeFan. When i run my pgm user enters some command line argument, I want the value of the argument in multiple namespaces which is not directly invoked from my main namespace. In java i can set the class/instance variable using a setter method and use the getter method in other objects to get the value. How is this accomplished in clojure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just store an atom in your global var:

```
(def global-var (atom nil))
```

Comment: Does it makes sense to call it a "global var" if it's an atom :) ?

Answer (score 3):

Note: this is in response to the third comment on the question. [dAni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34775847/1876583) applies to the question as asked.

Idiomatic Clojure favors functions whose outputs are determined only by their input parameters. This is in contrast to a function which relies on its parameters *and global state, too*. It is easy to convert a function which uses global data into one that does not - you just need to add a parameter that will contain the data. For example: instead of `(defn print-global [] (println @global-atom-defined-elsewhere))`, you use `(defn print-my-val [val] (println val))`.

If you use the command line argument extremely frequently, you might still find it more convenient to put the data in a global atom, instead of having everything use it as a parameter. This is up to you.